# Функция завершается сразу после вызова

Tags: c, функции

Доброго времени суток! У меня возникла проблема - функция завершается сразу после вызова, не требуя ввода строки (которую должна требовать). Функция находится в отдельном файле. В этом же проекте еще много функций, все они работают корректно. Сама функция:

```
int task14(void)
{
    char str[100];
    char str2[200];
    int i, j = 0;
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        str2[j] = str[i];
        str2[j + 1] = str[i];
        j += 2;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Мне кажется, что проблема в fgets, т.к. в остальных функциях использован scanf. Чем можно заменить fgets или если проблема не в нём, то в чём может быть? Я работаю в Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Только он вылезает за пределы массива; если условие в цикле заменить на `i < 100`, то всё прекрасно работает

Comment: @andreymal Насчёт цикла вы верно заметили. Вы вызвали эту функцию или просто запустили её в main?

Comment: Не понял этого предложения, я вызвал её в main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нострадамлю :), что перед этим где-то было считывание в духе `scanf("%d"` без сброса после этого буфера ввода, так что в нем остался `\n`, который и считывается `fgets`.

Чтобы убедиться - напишите после `fgets`, например,

```
printf("[%s]\n",str);
```

и посмотрите, что там будет...

Comment: Там именно то, что вы сказали, спасибо! Теперь возникает вопрос, как сбросить буфер ввода? Я попробовал fflush(stdin), теперь \n нет, то строка всё равно не считывается.

Comment: Ну, например, просто читайте по символу, пока не встретите `\n`. Что-то типа `int c;
do {
c = getchar();
} while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Не могу понять, как таким образом заполнить строку?

Comment: Это не заполнение строки, а сброс всего, что оставалось в буфере, до конца строки.

Comment: Я понял, getchar забирает символ из stdin! Теперь всё работает. Огромное спасибо!